# What cause info can be readily collected in an iOS signal handler?

Tags: ios, signals, error-logging

I'm trying to add some crash logging to an app, and I have a `signal` handler set up to catch the standard "fatal" signals.  What "cause" information (if any) can I practically/simply collect in the signal handler for logging?

(I've spent about 2 hours Googling stuff, but most of what i find is for other environments and is too complex to be reliable.  I'm looking for what's simple to do, specifically in an iOS environment.)

(I already have an Objective-C exception handler to catch Objective-C exceptions.)

Answer (score 3):

Please don't do this. It is incredibly hard to do proper and safe crash reporting, as highlighted by Landon Fuller here: http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/objc/Reliable_Crash_Reporting.20110912.html

In a nutshell: you may only use async safe code when the app crashed, so calling any Objective-C method is not safe by default!

Rather use an existing crash reporting library like PLCrashReporter or some other library or service that already exist: https://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/

Comment: What's the worst that can happen if you screw it up?

Comment: The linked article states some of them below the section "First, do no harm", like "This can deadlock the process and cause a hang, resulting in a failure to report the crash. In the pathological case, this can result in corruption of users' data." I can not stress this enough: don't do this yourself if you are not an expert in that area.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the stack trace with this:

```
+ (NSArray *)backtrace {
    void* callstack[128];
    int frames = backtrace(callstack, 128);
    char **strs = backtrace_symbols(callstack, frames);

    int i;
    NSMutableArray *backtrace = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:frames];
    for (i = 0; i < XXX; i++) {
        [backtrace addObject:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:strs[i]]];
    }
    free(strs);

    return backtrace;
}
```

Comment: From my reading, there's no guarantee that the signal handler is running in the same thread as the `raise`.

Comment: Yep, in a sample of one it dumps the wrong thread.  But a good start.