# Catching the crash log on iOS

Tags: ios, exception, swift, crash, plcrashreporter

The main idea is to catch the crash log (or the reason of the error) and send it to a server.
I know that iTunes does log the crashes from the users' devices but I need to find if there's a way to get it and store it on our server.

I was trying "PlCrashReporter" and i finished implementing it (as they did on this link https://www.plcrashreporter.org/documentation/api/v1.0/example_usage_iphone.html).

**Problem**

The function **applicationDidFinishLaunching** is not called when the crash occurs.

Am I on the right track? 
Is there a specific function which is called upon a crash in **AppDelegate** ?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I've also tried the solution of the following question:

[iOS crash log catch, debug info.. Catch and send via email to the Dev team](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233388/ios-crash-log-catch-debug-info-catch-and-send-via-email-to-the-dev-team)

It actually works but there are some errors that are cause by Swift and not Objective-C (Like **Error while unwrapping optional value**) were not caught..

Any suggestions?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325019/what-cause-info-can-be-readily-collected-in-an-ios-signal-handler

Comment: The crash report has to be send on the next app start. That is how PLCrashReporter also suggests to do it.

Comment: Is there any way to modify the code of PLCrashReporter to make it send the crash report on crash? @Kerni

Comment: It is highly recommended not to even try this, because it puts your users data at high risk for data corruption or even locking the device. Do *not* go that route!

Comment: What data specifically? @Kerni

Comment: Any data. Your app crashed which means it is in a highly unstable state where no guarantees can be made. E.g. even calling only one Objective-C or Swift method when the app crashed could cause data loss. Here is an article from the author of PLCrashReporter: http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/crashreporting/Reliable_Crash_Reporting_1.1.20130119.html I can only repeat myself: don't even think about going that route!

Comment: @Odin - Have you found the reason why its not catching those swift runtime errors ? But AFAIK crittercism and all catches this.

Comment: I invite you share your thoughts on this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/35557716/730807

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [Crashlytics](http://www.crashlytics.com). You then can use a custom web hook to receive the crash reports.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply.. I will check it asap and will reply my feedback :) @Moxy

Comment: Crashlytics is beta. I registered in line to get the app but in the mean time is there any alternative? @Moxy

Comment: Did they tell how much time it could take? You shouldn't reinvent the wheel. There are other services like splunkmint (formerly bugsense)

Comment: They didn't mention any time. I guess it's better not to use any beta frameworks to do this. I'll try to find another frameworks @Moxy

Comment: Crashlytics has existed for years and is not in beta! They have a feature called beta that lets you have beta users like testflight.