# NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler not catches the exception in swift But Crittercism does it

Tags: ios, swift, crash, crittercism, uncaughtexceptionhandler

Purpose of [NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSGetUncaughtExceptionHandler) is to catch the exception and dump it somewhere so that we can find why the app crashed and what is the exception.

In Objective C it catches the exception as expected..Here is the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20417064/730807)

But in swift when an exception arises its not caught. Here is the code that I used in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
 NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler { exception in
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("Exception Details Are \n\nExceptionName--> \(exception.name) \nReason -->\(exception.reason!)\n\(exception.description)", forKey: "Exception")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("Call Stack Symbols:\(exception.callStackSymbols)", forKey: "ExceptionCallstack")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
        }
```

Here is the snippet that I use to crash the app

```
    var c=["a","b","c"]
    var d=c[4]
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: How did you test that? (You cannot catch Swift runtime errors.)

Comment: Oh ! Is there anyway to catch swift runtime errors ? I have updated the question with the snippet that I use to crash the app.

Comment: As far as I know...swift is running on the same runtime as Objective C

Comment: I tried Crittercism it caught this error.But I don't want to implement any third party I want to catch my own errors and keep it inside the app.

Comment: I don't know what Crittercism is or does. To the best of my knowledge, you *cannot* catch Swift runtime errors (like `Array` out of bounds access, or unwrapping an `Optional` which is `nil`).

Answer (score 0):

Initialize Crittercism before installing the NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler.

And at the beginning of your handler, call:

[Crittercism logHandledException:exception]; // ObjC

or
   Crittercism.logHandledException(exception) // Swift

Comment: I am trying to catch the crash just using `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler` or some other native code without using third party like *Crittercism*